# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in single page application with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-page-application

```js
function Drawitems() {
  var $list = $("#shoppinglistitems").empty();
  //go through the list array to get elements ---->we will do that by using for loop 
  for (var i = 0; i < currentlist.items.length; i++) {
    var currentitem = currentlist.items[i];
    //create dom element for this list item
    var $li = $("<li>").html.currentitem.name.attr("id", "item_" + i)
    var $DeleteBt = $("<button>D</button>").appendTO($li);
    var $CheckBt = $("<button>C</button>").appendTO($li);
    $li.appendTO($list);
  }
```

When I try to show the application on google chrome i have the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>   so what can i do

Best Regards

Comment: `$("<li>").html.currentitem.name.attr("id", "item_" + i)` - Where is this construct coming from? O.o

Comment: Please take care to format your code correctly. This was completely unreadable until I edited it.

Comment: You have quite a few issues here. `html` is a method so should be `html()` however it returns a string, so I'm not sure why you're trying to rettrieve the `currentitem.name` property from it, much less cange the `attr()` of that. This is the source of the error. Also `appendTO()` needs to be `appendTo()`. Remember that JS is case-sensitive

Comment: Mr. andreas i did not under stand your question please clarify

Comment: Can you please post your html too. Also can you please explain what exactly you want to do with this code?

Comment: this is my HTML code for this part
<div id="theshoppingfrom" style="display:none;">
    <!-- the name of new list should be changed to be the text that entered in the first view -->
    <h1 id="shoppinglisttitle"> New List</h1>
    <input id="insertitems" type="text" placeholder="New Item"/>
    <button onclick="additemtolist()" > create</button>

Comment: One point for demostrating how difficult it is for javascript/jQuery "experts" to read code!!!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var $li = $("<li>").html(currentitem.name).attr("id", "item_" + i)
```